# Inline editing issues and questions for jqGrid

Tags: php, jqgrid, inline-editing

I'm trying to use inline editing in `jqGrid` and I'm having trouble with the return values.

If I use the `.jqGrid('navGrid'...` and set `edit:true`, I can just attach a function to the `afterComplete` property. I've got that working, but it isn't exactly what I want.

How do I do it when using inline editing?

I want to use the icons in the navigator to initiate the edit and save. I suppose I could overwrite the default methods to use my own version of `.jgrid('editRow'...`, but there has to be an easier way.

My other question is this. If I do end up using the `editRow` call and use the "successfunc" parameter, what do I send back from the `editurl` page (written in PHP) to indicate a success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I full understand your question.

To the first part of your question: I recommend you to use [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#inlinenav) method instead of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition). In the case the buttons added in the navigator will use inline editing.

To you another question: jqGrid use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) internally to communicate with the server. The main indicator for `jQuery.ajax` and so jqGrid whether the server response was successful is [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). So if the server returns 200 status code (OK) then the response will be interpret as successful. If the server response and code starting with 400 `jQuery.ajax` calls `error` callback. So it would be better to use `errorfunc` to decode the error response (if needed) and use `aftersavefunc` to do some actions on successful saving of the row.

Comment: Thanks for the response on the server communication. I think I have that part down now.  <br/>

Comment: I think I have that part down now. I want to use inlineNav, but I can't figure out how to grab the response from the server. I now understand how to send the response, but I don't know how to catch it? I see how to use aftersavefunc if using rowEdit, but not if I am using inlineNav and not explicitly calling rowEdit.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user1118374: In the most case you don't need analyse the server response. If you do need that you can use `$("#grid_id").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', { 
   edit: true, editParams: {aftersavefunc: function (rowid, response) {alert('rowid=' + rowid + '\nserver response=' + response)} });`

Comment: Thank you! I never tried it while sending a valid response. I assumed that I would need to catch the status and then do something with it. My code works perfectly now. Thank you!!